# SQL Server 2008:: Efficient way to do the following query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have the following data:

**Input**:

```
   ----------------------------
   | Id | Value|
   ----------------------------
   | 1  |A     |
   | 1  |B     |
   | 2  |C     |
   | 2  |D     |
   | 2  |E     |
   | 3  |F     |
   ----------------------------
```

I need to convert the results to the following:

**Output** (Count is based on Id)

```
   ----------------------------
   | Id | Value| Count|
   ----------------------------
   | 1  |A     | 2    |
   | 1  |B     | 2    |
   | 2  |C     | 3    |
   | 2  |D     | 3    |
   | 2  |E     | 3    |
   | 3  |F     | 1    |
   ----------------------------
```

I am using SQL server 2008. Is it possible to write a query to do this?
If yes could anyone help me provide a SQL to obtain the above output from the input data I gave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `COUNT OVER`:

```
select id, value, count(*) over (partition by id)
from mytable
order by id, value;
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.. But I have one more problem.. The input which I showed you was from a temp table. which is created as "Select distinct id,value from MainTable where date='20181201' and id is not null and value is not null". If I your query on temp table it works.. But if I use the same query on Main table with distinct, it does not work. Could you kindly help on that?

Comment: @DeepakKumar . . . Ask *another* question and put your query in the question.  Comments are not an appropriate place to ask questions.